# What is the scrope of varibles in block in jinja?

Tags: scope, range, jinja2

First, I am not asking about something about loop (for)! 
In Jinja, I feel confused about the valid scope of variables defined inside and outside a block. For example, If I define {% set a = ... %} inside a block, can I use it in another block? If I defined them in super-class, in the child class, in what kind of range can I use them? I found sometimes it is passed from one block to another (or from here to there), and sometimes not. I do not find any document to explain that.
(What I mean "pass" is to use {{a}} directly and it returns the valid value.)

Answer (score 0):

Variables in `block`, `for`, `macro` and `filter` are all local. They are valid only inside these block.
Detail can be found [here](https://svn.python.org/projects/external/Jinja-1.2/docs/src/scopes.txt). An example given there is:

.. sourcecode:: jinja

```
{% macro angryhello name %}
  {% set angryname = name|upper %}
  Hello {{ name }}. Hello {{ name }}!
  HELLO {{ angryname }}!!!!!!111
{% endmacro %}
```

The variable `angryname` just exists inside the macro, not outside it.